# Someone detected my location on Omegle

Tags: geolocation

I was in Omegle and was chatting with someone when he told me "wanna make a bet?" and I say sure why not.

He tells me he can identify my location and proceeds to put all my internet connection information and computer.

Then he tells me the town city and country I live in (not my complete address)
Should I be worried?

Answer (score 14):

TL;DR - No, this is common on omegle..

In order for Omegle to work. It connects every pair via UDP. This exposes the currently paired client's ip address. They were simply running wireshark, found your IP address and ran a lookup on it.

[Here is a youtube example of this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qqsH62ehgfM).

Comment: I wouldn't have thought they'd even need to run wireshark - the information's probably there in "netstat"...

Comment: @psmears: netstat works best on connections (TCP). It can show local listening UDP sockets, but not remote hosts that have sent or will send data to that socket.

Comment: @MSalters: I know. I'm just suggesting there will be a "connected" UDP socket there when an Omegle session is up. ("connected" in the sense that `connect()` has been called on it - obviously there isn't actually a "real" connection for UDP...)